# Change or remove Firebase user Property to particular user

Tags: firebase, events, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am working on firebase analytics.

the focus topic for my problem is `User property`.

**Issue**

Suppose my Application connected with firebase with a unique Login token to `Firebase User Id`

now I make `User property` to firebase is `hobbies` ok?

now I set user property `hobbies` = "Reading" & "traveling" with the associate user id.

after some time that Pericular **user** remove `hobbies` = "Reading"

So my question is

How can I **remove/untag**  `"reading"` user property from firebase to a particular `user id`.

tell me if any more specification needed

Comment: Did you try `firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({hobbies: 'Reading'});`(or the equivalent in the platform you're using)? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: But Question is first time i set

`firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({hobbies: 'Reading'})` &
`firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({hobbies: 'traveling'})`

ok so for that user two property  set/add/tag.
now how can I remove/ untag  reading property to that user.

like `firebase.analytics().removeUserProperties({hobbies: 'Reading'})`

@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I don't think a user-property can have such a multi-value as you're trying to use here. It's a single value, not an array/set. I'd sooner model the adding/removing of hobbies as separate events. Then again, I'm pretty new to analytics, so don't know if that is a common practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.